# pypeg: what does str or List mean?

Tags: python, parsing

Trying to parse expression like
name(arg1,arg2...)

So I try:

```
from pypeg2 import *

class Type (str):
    grammar = attr ('type', re.compile (r'[a-z]+'))

class args (List):
    grammar = maybe_some ( csl (word) )

class Gen (str):
    grammar = Type, '(', args, ')'
```

First I tried deriving Gen from List, but then I get
GrammarTypeError: in grammar: '('

I don't understand what it means to be derived from 'str', or derived from 'List'.  Where can I find an explanation?

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you having trouble with?

Comment: I was trying to follow the example of List found [link](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/grammar_elements.html#list).  It seems identical to what I was trying, I don't understand why mine gave an error on the '(', the only difference I can see is I used '(' and the example used '{'

Comment: @nbecker Did you use python 3? Or you would need to import unicode_literal from __future__ module if you were at python2.7

Answer (score 0):

try this changes:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import re
from pypeg2 import *

class Type (str):
    grammar = attr ('type', Symbol)

class args (List):
    grammar = maybe_some ( csl (word) )

class Gen (str):
    grammar = Type, '(', args, ')'

teste = "name(arg1,arg2, arg3)"

k = parse(teste, Gen)

print(k)
```